# How to reset IE9

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

There is a Reset button in IE in `Tools-> Internet Options-> Advanced Tab`. The problem is, when the button is pushed, it says that all IE windows and programs should be closed. Since the Internet Options form is a Modal form that stays on top of IE, it prevents IE from closing. Is there any command line or alternate option that can be run to reset IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Work Around - Windows 7

1. Click **Start** icon
2. Type: `Internet Option`
3. Click on **Internet Option**
4. Click the **Advanced** tab
5. Click the **Reset...** button

#### Alternate Way - Windows XP/Vista/7

1. Open up the **Control Panel**
2. Locate **Internet** or **Internet Option** icon

   - Wind XP: If in *Category View* switch to *Classic View*
3. Double-Click on the icon
4. Click the **Advanced** tab
5. Click the **Reset...** button

Answer (score 3):

If you just wish to fix it, this works in win 7 and should work in other Microsoft versions.
If you only wanted 'Command Line' sorry.
You can open internet options on its own by typing into search 'Internet Options',
or clicking on 'Internet Options' in control panel.

Comment: yes, that is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to call the powershell cmdlet found on this site, from a .bat:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Internet-Explorer-20f838e7

```
powershell.exe .\Reset-Ie-Default.ps1
```

Works like a charm, but does require some input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

To perform what the reset button does:

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults
```

To delete all caches and settings “Also delete files and settings stored by add-ons”:

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this batch file:

```
@echo off
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO =========================================
ECHO Please Run Privilege Elevation Tool First
ECHO =========================================

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.
ECHO ******************************************
ECHO Please Run Privilege Elevation Tool First
ECHO ******************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 

cmdkey.exe /list > "%TEMP%\List.txt"
findstr.exe Target "%TEMP%\List.txt" > "%TEMP%\tokensonly.txt"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%G IN (%TEMP%\tokensonly.txt) DO cmdkey.exe /delete:%%H
del "%TEMP%\*.*" /s /f /q

taskkill.exe /F /IM iexplore.exe /T

rundll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

rundll32 inetcpl.cpl ResetIEtoDefaults

gpupdate.exe /force
```

Comment: I think your answer would benefit from proper formatting and explanation what your batch file is doing. To make it better, I'd format code as code and explain briefly major points of the script.